# Play multiple animation on same object at same time (Unity)

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

I have created two animation for the same object, lets say fly animation and forward animation, but I want to play both animation simultaneously. I've researched for it, and I get something like using Animation.blendMode and Animation.weight. But i can't get how to use it? Is there any proper example for this?

Comment: I think what you want is to *blend* the animations - read all about it at unity

Answer (score 0):

I have read that using Animation Layers (http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimationLayers.html) is for parallel animations. But I have never tried it.